# Не могу центрировать список в HTML с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css

Решил сделать красивый список, погуглил, скопировал код, подгоняю под себя.
Вот, собственно, сам код:

```css
/* HTML */

html {
    overflow:  hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #00bebe url('https://i.imgur.com/lfzKuZH.png') center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}



/* BODY */

body {
    margin: 0;
}



/* H TAGS */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #EC542A;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 30px 0 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
}



/* UL, OL */

ul, ol{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}



/* LI */

li {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}



/* CONTANER */

#contaner {
    width: 100%;
}



/* ROUNDED */

.rounded ol, .rectangle ol {
    list-style: none; 
}

.rounded, .rectangle{
    counter-reset: li;
    list-style: none;
    font: 14px "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans";padding: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.rounded a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
    margin: .5em 0 0 1.3em;;
    background: #DAD2CA;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.rounded a:hover {
    background: #E9E4E0;
}

.rounded a:hover:before {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.rounded a:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    background: #8FD4C1;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: .3em solid white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}



/* CENTRED */

.centred {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lists</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="data/css/listsstyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great|Poiret+One|Marck+Script|EB+Garamond&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contaner">
            <h3>Пример 1.</h3>
            <ol class="rounded">  
                <li class="cented"><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>  
                <li class="cented"><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>  
                <li class="cented"><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>  
                <li class="cented"><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>  
                <li class="cented"><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Вопрос: как сделать список по центру экрана, чтобы он не съезжал никуда.
Пробовал делать `display: flex`, но всё выравнивается в одну линию, что меня не устраивает.
Хотелось бы увидеть универсальное свойство, т.к. часто приходится что-то центрировать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас стиль в css называется ***centred***, а поля имеют класс ***cented***
 Для выравнивания есть множество вариантов. 
 К примеру использование ***margin: auto;***

```css
   html {
    overflow:  hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #00bebe url('https://i.imgur.com/lfzKuZH.png') center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}



/* BODY */

body {
    margin: 0;
}



/* H TAGS */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #EC542A;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 30px 0 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
}



/* UL, OL */

ul, ol{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}



/* LI */

li {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}



/* CONTANER */

#contaner {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}



/* ROUNDED */

.rounded ol, .rectangle ol {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.rounded, .rectangle{
    text-align: center;
    counter-reset: li;
    list-style: none;
    font: 14px "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans";padding: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.rounded a {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
    margin: .5em 0 0 1.3em;;
    background: #DAD2CA;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.rounded a:hover {
    background: #E9E4E0;
}

.rounded a:hover:before {
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.rounded a:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    background: #8FD4C1;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: .3em solid white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}



/* CENTRED */

.cented {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lists</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="data/css/listsstyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great|Poiret+One|Marck+Script|EB+Garamond&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contaner">
            <h3>Пример 1.</h3>
            <ol class="rounded">  
                <li class="cented"><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>  
                <li class="cented"><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>  
                <li class="cented"><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>  
                <li class="cented"><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>  
                <li class="cented"><a href="#">Элемент списка</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```